# How to edit an existing commit in git

Tags: git

I want to edit an old commit in git. How do I undo just a part of an old commit?
(I am a bit of a git rookie, so sorry if I am confused about terms etc).

Example: in a commit, say three commits back, I deleted some code that should not have been deleted (yet). Now I want to go back and undo *that* particular change of that commit. It's a local repo.

What I have tried is what google gives me: stash + rebase -i + amend, but these invariably end up in a mess that takes (me) hours to resolve. None of them lets me actually edit the commit, only to do new changes - which in case of deleted code means me to locate and re-enter the deleted lines again, by hand (cut and paste). Then, even if the rebase is successful, the stash pop always fails... with a merge mess on my hands..). There just must be an easier way!

When I do a `git add -p`, it allows me edit the commit, line-by-line, and confirm what goes in. Now I want to redo that process, but on a commit. A `git unadd -p` of sorts, allowing me to delete the lines in the .patch with '-' in front.

Sorry, if my frustration with this comes through.

Comment: Your commit history is like a building. Old commits form the base of the building and newer commits form the top. You have built a building. Now you want to change the base of the building which is generally not possible without breaking everything that comes on top of that base. The best solution imo is to checkout to that specific commit where you deleted your important file. Copy that file. Then checkout to your master. And then paste that file.

Comment: How does that work with `git bisect`, which is the killer feature I love in git? If a commit I made 180 commits ago breaks the build with certain combination of preprocessor options enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You literally *can't* edit any existing commit.  This is most of why what you're doing is leading to blind alleys.  You can't think of it as *changing a commit;* you need to think of it differently.

What you *can* do—and are trying to do based on various instructions—is to use the existing commits, which give you the ability to "go back in time" as it were, to go back in time to a good starting point, and then build *new* commits that you use *instead of* the existing bad commits:

```
<-- older -------------------------------------- newer -->
...  <-commit3  <-commit4  <-commit5  <-...  <-last-commit
```

By "rewinding" in time to, say, commit4, then making a *new and improved version* of commit #5, followed by a new and improved version of commit #6, and so on, we end up with this:

```
           E--F--G--H   [abandoned]
          /
A--B--C--D
          \
           E'-F'-G'-H'  <-- main
```

Here, instead of numbering the commits, I've used letters: commit `A` is the first one, `B` is the second, and so on.  That, and I got lazy about drawing the arrows: they come out of each commit and point backwards, but for easier drawing, I just drew connecting lines this time.  I also added a branch name, in this case, `main`.

There are numerous keys to making this work and making it easier:

- Any *uncommitted* work *cannot be handled this way*.  You must *commit* stuff.  I don't like `git stash` myself, but the point of using `git stash` is that it *commits your work*.  (The main thing that makes a stash commit—really, a pair of commits, that `git stash` makes at the same time—special is that it's not on *any* branch at all.  This makes it easy to "move" to another branch—because it's not *on* any branch—but really hard to work with.)  I recommend just making an actual commit, if you have uncommitted stuff.
- The *interactive* rebase is the way to tell Git to stop after it copies a commit, and let you make changes.  There's a learning curve here though.  It really is tricky to do, the first few times.
- Remember that each commit is uniquely identified by its hash ID.  It's the hash ID that is the "true name" of a commit.  When you start copying commits to new-and-improved commits, the original commits are still there!  Some operations may still be able to see them, and you'll see duplicates.  If you have not yet *finished* the copying process, this is quite normal: do not be alarmed.  If you *have* finished the copying process, things are trickier.
- Remember that Git *finds* commits by working *backwards*.  A *branch name* like `main` or `master`, or `develop`, or `feature/short`, or whatever you may be using, literally contains the raw hash ID of the *last* commit in some chain.  That last commit points backwards to an earlier (second-to-last) commit; the earlier commit points backwards yet again; and so on.

  This is why we "rewind and rebuild".  If something was wrong in commit `E`, we rewind to commit `D`: the point before things went wrong.

  Unfortunately, rewinding to point `D` means we can't *see* commit `E` any more—not with `git log` anyway, which starts at the *current commit* (now `D`) and works backwards.  But `git log branch-name` will still start at the end and work backwards.  This is where you'll potentially see duplicates: once you've made your new-and-improved `E'`, `git log` will start at `E'` and work backwards, while `git log branch-name` will start at `H` and work backwards.  Note that `H` goes back to `G`, `G` goes to `F`, and `F` goes to `E`, so you see only `E` this time.  The *hash ID* of `E` is different from that of your new and improved `E'`, but the *commit message* is the same.

Let's get into some of the more detailed aspects of rebasing now.

#### Branch names and `HEAD`

Let's start with the normal, attached-HEAD setup:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

Here, we are on our `main` branch.  The *latest* commit is commit `H`.  The special name `HEAD` is *attached to* the name `main`, and `git log` shows commit `H`, then commit `G`, then commit `F`, and so on.

Let's look at a more complicated repository with several branch names:

```
          I--J   <-- develop (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- feature
```

Here, we did a `git checkout develop` to get onto our `develop` branch.  Its latest commit is commit `J`.  Commit `J` leads back to commit `I`, which leads back to `H`—which is the last commit of `main`, but just a middle commit of `develop`.  A simple `git log` will show `J`, then `I`, then `H`, and so on.

If we run `git checkout feature` now, `git log` will show commit `L` first, then `K`, then `H`, then `G`, and so on.  Again, Git just works *backwards*, one commit at a time.  The commits up through and including `H` are on *all three branches*.

#### Detached HEAD mode

If we want to check out some *historic* commit—one that does not have a branch name pointing to it—such as commit `F`, one way we can do that, in Git, is to run `git checkout` with a raw hash ID.

In this case, our drawing might look more like this:

```
...--E--F   <-- HEAD
         \
          G--H   <-- main
```

I've left out any other branches because there's not enough room to draw them in.  Note how the special name `HEAD` is no longer attached to any branch name, though: it just picks out the *current commit* directly.  This is why `git log` will start by showing you commit `F`, not commit `H`, and then work backwards from there.

#### Rebase uses detached HEAD mode

The `git rebase` command uses this detached-HEAD mode.  Let's say that we have `main` ending at commit `H`, followed by `dev` with four more commits, and we're on `dev`:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J--K--L   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

Running `git rebase -i HEAD~3` will give us an instruction sheet that says:

```
pick <hash-of-J>
pick <hash-of-K>
pick <hash-of-L>
```

If we change `pick` to `edit` on all three of these, write out the instruction sheet, and exit the editor, Git now starts by *copying `J`*, more or less like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J--K--L   <-- dev
           \
            J'  <-- HEAD
```

Because we said "edit", Git stops *after* copying `J` to `J'`.<sup>1</sup>  This gives us a chance to make file changes, run `git add`, and then run `git commit --amend`.

What `--amend` does is tricky.  Git literally *can't* change `J'`.  It can, however, make yet another new commit—let's call this one `J"` to indicate that it's a modified copy of `J'`, which itself was a mostly-unmodified copy of `J`—but set things up so that `J"` points back to `I`, not to `J'`:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J--K--L   <-- dev
          |\
          | J'  [abandoned]
           \
            J"  <-- HEAD
```

We now instruct `git rebase` to `--continue`, and it goes on to copy `K` to `K'`.<sup>2</sup>  If we stop drawing in `J'`—there's no way to *find* it so we don't need to draw it any more—this looks like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J--K--L   <-- dev
           \
            J"-K'  <-- HEAD
```

If we now make changes, use `git add`, and use `git commit --amend`, we make a new commit `K"` and abandon `K'`:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J--K--L   <-- dev
           \
            J"-K'  [abandoned]
             \
              K"  <-- HEAD
```

Again, we just stop bothering drawing `K'` after this, so that our next picture is:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J--K--L   <-- dev
           \
            J"-K"-L'  <-- HEAD
```

and this gives us the opportunity to modify and `git commit --amend` yet again.

---

<sup>1</sup>In this particular case, Git will "cheat" and just re-use `J` directly, unless we add more options to our `git rebase` command.  But I don't want to get into these details.

<sup>2</sup>This time Git really does have to copy `K`: it really *can't* re-use the original.  That's why I wanted to pretend that Git had to copy `J` earlier, to simplify what's going on.

---

#### This is crazy, it's too hard

It kind of *is* crazy and hard, but once you've done a few of these, it isn't *too* hard after all.  You just have to remember a few things:

- Commits (and branch names) are cheap.  Git is perfectly willing to make dozens of commits, just to throw them away in the future.  What we really want, in the end, is a series of commits that we *keep*, by keeping a branch name pointing to the last one.  If we abandon an old commits, so that there's no way to *find* it, Git will eventually get rid of it.<sup>3</sup>
- The above sequence of `git rebase` copying one commit at a time is just a fancy automated way to run `git cherry-pick` over and over again.  We *have* to do that because we can't actually *change* any existing commit, so we have to copy the old commits to new ones.  The cherry-pick command is the internal Git command that copies *one* commit.
- Because Git works *backwards*, and no commit can ever be changed, "replacing" even just *one* old commit somewhere in the middle of a chain, such as making a new-and-improved `J'` to replace the original `J`, *requires* copying all subsequent commits.

So that's why `git rebase` does this crazy thing of copying every commit.  Using `pick` means *do the cherry-pick, then move on to the next commit*.  Using `edit` means *do the cherry-pick, but then stop.*  Once Git stops, you get a chance to *replace* the commit it just made.  You can replace it with two commits, or remove it entirely, or whatever you want to do ... then you resume the cherry-picking with `git rebase --continue`.

---

<sup>3</sup>"Eventually" usually means that at least 30 days must pass from the time we made the commits, due to what Git calls *reflog entries*.  The details are not really important here: just know that if you just now finished a rebase, but then decide you hate the result, it's easy to *undo* it.  Later—as time goes by—it gets harder, and after the 30+ days have passed, it may become impossible.

---

#### Using interactive rebase and fixup/squash

There's a common pattern that recurs when making changes and then redoing work:

- You make some change and commit.
- You make a second change and commit.
- You make a third, etc., change, or don't, and commit or don't, but at this point you realize you introduced a bug in the first change, or anyway one that's not the current one.

Rather than going back and fixing it *right now*, Git's `rebase -i` now has a feature where you can make a fixing commit as soon as you're ready, then use `git rebase -i` to *rearrange and combine* the fixing commit with the original commit.

Let's use your example from the top:

> ... in a commit, say three commits back, I deleted some code that should not have been deleted (yet). Now I want to go back and undo that particular change of that commit. It's a local repo.

So, you had something working, and a branch tip (maybe `main`).  You created a new branch name `dev`:

```
git checkout -b dev
```

Then you made commit #1, then #2, then #3, then #4:

```
<some hacking>
git commit -m "prepare for delete"
<delete some stuff>
git commit -m "delete bad things"
<more hacking>
git commit -m "add first part of good things"
<more hacking>
git commit -m "add second part of good things"
```

You're in the middle of working on #5 right now when you realize you deleted too much stuff in #2, "delete bad things".  If you don't *have* to put the code back *right now*, go ahead and finish #5 and commit:

```
<hacking>
git commit -m "add third part of good things"
```

Now you can use `git revert`, `git checkout -p`, `git revert -n` and `git reset -p`, or whatever you like to prepare to restore the deleted-too-much parts of commit #2.  When that's ready, run:

```
git commit --fixup <hash of commit #2>
```

Git makes a commit that has the effect of restoring the lines you didn't want to delete.  This is a commit-#6 in your series, but its *subject line* is:

```
fixup! delete bad things
```

Later, you can run:

```
git rebase -i --autosquash main
```

to rebase `dev` onto `main` using the auto-squash / auto-fix-up mode.  Git will:

- locate the `delete bad things` commit;
- move the commit that *restores* a few lines to come just after the `delete bad things` commit in the instruction sheet; and
- change the `pick` line here to `fixup`.

This `fixup` instruction tells `git rebase` that, when it comes to that point in the commit series, it should not *stop* at that point, but rather *combine* the delete commit with the restore commit, drop the `fixup` commit's *commit log message*, and then proceed with the remainder of the `pick` lines.

It's best to try this out in a scratch repository, playing with the interactive rebase to learn how squash and fixup commits work first, then start turning on autosquash mode.  In the end, though, it turns out to be quite powerful and useful.

Comment: Thank you for the very long response. Feeling bad to have you write that, it is similar to what I find elsewhere. Trying to explain, but not answering the question. You dropped a gem here: `git rebase` is an automated `git cherry-pick`. Wouldn't then a `git format-patch`, a `vi 0xyz-blah.patch` and `git am`, then do what I want?

Comment: In fact, the older `git rebase` *does* use `git format-patch` and `git am`, more or less. This is somewhat defective in that it doesn't handle renames well and cannot re-perform merges, but it tends to run a lot faster than the versions that do cherry-picks. You could in fact use that, if you like.

Answer (score 1):

I'll model it for you. Here's the starting situation:

```
% git log --oneline --graph
* b7ba319 (HEAD -> main) four
* 503d08a three
* 4e98a2f two
* c7f6c15 one
```

Now, it happens that back in `two` I made a mistake and changed "good" to "bad" in the file *a.txt*. Let's examine *a.txt* in every commit to see the story:

```
% git show @~3:a.txt
this is a good line
this is okay
so is this
this is fine
whatever
this is all right
========
% git show @~2:a.txt
this is a bad line
this is okay
so is this
this is fine
whatever
this is all right
this is okay too
========
% git show @~1:a.txt
this is a bad line
this is okay
so is this
this is fine
whatever
this is all right
this is okay too
I like this
========
% git show @:a.txt  
this is a bad line
this is okay
so is this
this is fine
whatever
this is all right
this is okay too
I like this
this is great
```

Okay, now I propose to go back and fix up `two`. I'll use interactive rebase:

```
% git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Inside the editor, here's what I say:

```
edit 4e98a2f two
pick 503d08a three
pick b7ba319 four
```

I close the editor, and Git says:

```
Stopped at 4e98a2f...  two
You can amend the commit now, with

  git commit --amend 

Once you are satisfied with your changes, run

  git rebase --continue
```

Okay, I'll do just what Git told me to do. I edit *a.txt* and fix it up, changing "bad" to "good" in the first line:

```
% pico a.txt
```

Now I'm done editing, so I let Git know about the change:

```
% git add .
% git commit --amend
% git rebase --continue
```

Git finishes the rebase. Let's review what the history of *a.txt* is now:

```
% git show @~3:a.txt
this is a good line
this is okay
so is this
this is fine
whatever
this is all right
========
% git show @~2:a.txt
this is a good line
this is okay
so is this
this is fine
whatever
this is all right
this is okay too
========
% git show @~1:a.txt
this is a good line
this is okay
so is this
this is fine
whatever
this is all right
this is okay too
I like this
========
% git show @:a.txt  
this is a good line
this is okay
so is this
this is fine
whatever
this is all right
this is okay too
I like this
this is great
```

As you can see, I successfully changed the history from `two` all the way forward. I believe that's what you said you wanted.

Note that, as you've been told, this involves replacing commits. The SHA numbers have all changed:

```
% git log --oneline --graph
* 6c10f14 (HEAD -> main) four
* 1058899 three
* 0e05cba two
* c7f6c15 one
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few concepts to straighten out here, but I'll try to keep each one brief.

### How do I decide what goes into a commit?

As you already know, before you can commit any changes, you have to run some version of [git add](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add). What this does is apply those changes to a kind of "work-in-progress commit" called the "staging area" (and occasionally also the "cache" or the "index"; git is not very consistent with its terminology).

### What if I change my mind?

"Unstaging" changes has traditionally been one of many jobs of the rather confusing "git reset" command, but in recent versions we have the more straight-forward [git restore](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore). Specifically, the opposite of "git add" is "git restore --staged" or "git restore -S" for short. Like "git add", you can either list whole files and directories, or use "--patch" ("-p" for short) to interactively choose "hunks" to restore.

### What if I've already committed?

The above commands determine what goes into the *next* commit, but what if you want to change the *last* commit instead? For that, you can use the [git commit --amend](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---amend) command.

Although intuitive, the name "amend" is slightly misleading here: a commit in git can never be edited, because its identity (the commit hash) is based on its entire contents. It might be better to have called it "git commit --replace".

The way it works is that you "stage" some changes with "git add" as normal, which creates a new snapshot in the "staging area"; but instead of being a child of the currently checked out commit, the new commit is put into history *instead of* that commit. In effect, it creates a parallel universe, where that is what you committed in the first place.

### How do I get the old version back?

In order to make the new version of the commit, we need to get the old code from somewhere. Again, the "git restore" command is our friend here, because we can specify the *source* we want to restore changes from. In this case, we want to restore from "the parent of the current commit", which can be written as "HEAD^" ("HEAD" being the currently checked out commit, and "^" translating roughly to "parent of").

So we can interactively put code from *before* the current commit into the staging area, and then *replace* the current commit with a new version, like so:

```
git restore --source=HEAD^ --staged --patch
git commit --amend
```

### What if I need to go back further?

As already mentioned, git's commits are *immutable*, but just as we can replace *one* commit with "git commit --amend", we can replace *a whole sequence of commits* with the powerful but complex [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

Essentially, a rebase looks at a series of commits and tries to "replay" them as though you were making the same changes again. It has various uses, but the one we're interested in here is ["interactive mode"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode), which lets you go back in time and do things slightly differently this time.

If you run "git rebase -i" and mark a commit as "edit", git replays the commit, and then pauses. This puts you into the same situation as if you'd changed your mind immediately after you committed - you can fix the parts you committed by mistake, and replace the commit with "git commit --amend".

Once you've finished with that commit, you run "git rebase --continue", and the rebase continues forwards through history, creating an alternative reality where that was the version you committed.

### An important warning

Whenever you "rewrite history", you are creating a series of new commits, with new commit hashes. If there are any other branches which were based on the original commits, they will become stranded in an alternative history, and need to be rebased in turn.

It's therefore generally considered a bad idea to rewrite the history of any branch that has been "shared" - that is, which anyone has based other work on.